# Magento 2.2.6 Customer Password Reset

Tags: error, magento2.2.6, password-recovery, change-password, troubleshooting

I have a problem with customer password reset in Magento 2.2.6 
After pressing forgot password it send me an email `" Set a New Password link "`

but when i am trying to set new password i got a message

```
Something went wrong while saving the new password.
```

[image: Here a Pic of error message]

Also i checked

> var/logs

But i dont have any problem with this all kind of emails setting are correct..
Any suggest?

Comment: Can you check the log files?

Comment: as i said i've already checked but no errors there :/

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if issue not solve.

Comment: did you add custom module? try to disable one by one your custom module and try again, maybe something in your custom module did it (custom module that works for customer module)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Magento 2.2.6 and Magento 2.2.7. Go to the file vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/AccountManagement.php and patch it like this:

```
       Fix M2.2.7 - MAGETWO-96079: Cannot update password using received link

diff --git a/Model/AccountManagement.php b/Model/AccountManagement.php
index 8f25651..b5b1905 100644
--- a/Model/AccountManagement.php
+++ b/Model/AccountManagement.php
@@ -670,8 +670,8 @@ class AccountManagement implements AccountManagementInterface
         $customerSecure->setRpTokenCreatedAt(null);
         $customerSecure->setPasswordHash($this->createPasswordHash($newPassword));
         $this->getAuthentication()->unlock($customer->getId());
-        $this->sessionManager->destroy();
         $this->destroyCustomerSessions($customer->getId());
+        $this->sessionManager->destroy();
         $this->customerRepository->save($customer);

         return true;
```

More info:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/7443dc3194040e9ce2f7baf902470deb975b97c6
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/18256

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this query in your database. It's just for temporary solution :

```
UPDATE `customer_entity`
SET `password_hash` = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxYOURPASSWORD', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1')
WHERE `entity_id` = add_your_customer_id_here;
```

Where The xxxxxxxx character sequence is a cryptographic salt, it is saved in `app\etc\env.php` file

```
<?php
return array (
  ...
  'crypt' => 
  array (
    'key' => '5bb9352691e3aea2ae49ae5229f5c83a', //cryptographic salt
  ),
  ...
```